# Maven: get csm/connection for dependencies

Tags: maven, github

We have a lot of maven artifact for internal use, and we need away to organize all these dependencies and map them to the github repository that's mentioned in csm/connection of these dependencies.

```
  <scm>
        <connection>github_URL</connection>
        ...
  </scm>
```

So is there an elegant way to get csm/connection of a each dependency of a pom file?

Comment: Can you please given an example and show what you mean cause to be honest I don't understand your question...

Comment: Ah...Thanks. So you have several projects which are built and produces artifacts which already have groupId/artifactId and version..So you need a mapping to your git repo url ? Didn't you already have that ? Or do I misunderstand a thing here?

Comment: Yes, but they are about 100 projects and they will be increasing, and all are used on main pom file, think about it as parent pom of our use, we need to get a map of those dependencies with their repo url from that pom.

Comment: what do you mean by "all are used on main pom file" ? Could make an example ? Would really help? If I correctly get it you need a kind of pattern to define the url for git and get back to GA or vice versa?

Comment: Let that I have 100 projects each one has its own repo, and they produces an artifact and uploaded to, say, nexus.
Let all these 100 artifact are used on single project as dependencies, and I want to get a map each dependency and its repo that is mentioned in scm/connection.

Comment: This is coming one thing into my mind: You are using all these different "repos/deps" within a single project as dependency...If so this sounds like those deps should be part of the single project so you can compile/build/refactor within a single repo and using the IDE to helpt...Furthermore if you build that single project all pom's will be download during the build and so you have all pom's with their scm part available? I would simply write a maven plugin for this to get those information...?

Comment: I have the same use case and problem. @khmarbaise did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well I managed to get this using a `bash script`, `perl` and `mvn-dependency-plugin`

In your main maven project run the following command:

```
  mvn clean dependency:unpack-dependencies -Dmdep.unpack.includes=**/pom.xml
```

This will unpack all `pom.xml` files of all dependencies in `target/dependency` directory.

Then run the following bash script:

```
for pom in $(find target/dependency/META-INF/maven -name 'pom.xml'); 
    do cat $pom | perl -n -e '/<connection>(.*)<\/connection>/ && print "$1\n"';
done
```

This will iterate for all `pom.xml` files and print all the scm connection strings in all modules.